# calibre default installation location

Tags: upgrade, 12.10, calibre

I want to upgrade my calibre,an ebook management. From it's site all I need just do the following:

```
sudo python -c "import sys; py3 = sys.version_info[0] > 2; u = __import__('urllib.request' if py3 else 'urllib', fromlist=1); exec(u.urlopen('http://status.calibre-ebook.com/linux_installer').read()); main()"
```

however, once I executed it's asking me:

```
Enter the installation directory for calibre [/opt]:
```

does anyone know the default installation location of calibre installed by USC?

Answer (score 2):

further down on their page it says

> You can prevent the installer from asking for the installation
>   directory by specifying it in the install command itself, as shown
>   below:
>
> ```
> sudo python -c "import sys; py3 = sys.version_info[0] > 2; u = __import__('urllib.request' if py3 else 'urllib', fromlist=1); exec(u.urlopen('http://status.calibre-ebook.com/linux_installer').read()); main(install_dir='/opt')"
> ```
>
> Change /opt above to whatever directory you want calibre automatically
>   installed to.

Presumably that means its default is /opt/calibre

On my system its in /usr/lib/calibre but it was installed through the ubuntu repo (NOT ADVISABLE but my school admin doesn't want unofficial installs of anything). So I can't confirm it but I'd be surprised if it isn't there.

Try seeing if the modified command works. If that doesn't work, search your filesystem for the calibre directory, then just replace /opt in main(install_dir='/opt')  to the directory calibre is installed in.